# I want show output like below image in the lwc datatable ,

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, datatable, matrix

[image: Inquiry, Transaction, Form, account Maintenace and Others are nothing but the controlling picklist(Call_Activity__c) values, while, Loans,Plan Regulation,Plan Overview, money management are dependent picklist(Call_Types__c) values]

About Table: Inquiry, Transaction, Form, account Maintenace and Others are nothing but the controlling picklist(Call_Activity__c) values, while, Loans,Plan Regulation,Plan Overview, money management are dependent picklist(Call_Types__c) values. So ,for particular call_activity__c, we want to show its respective call_Types__c values vertically in the datatable.

In the wire method we r using this apex class query to fetch the data...Now , I want to map this data in the datatable as shown in the below image.

```java
objCaseList =[SELECT  Case__r.CaseNumber,Case__r.CreatedDate,PlanID_Text__c,Call_Activity__c,Call_Type__c FROM Case_Actions__c where  Case__r.Account.SSN__c IN  ('010820241')];
        
return  objCaseList;
```

Javascript code:

```js
import { LightningElement,api,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import EXAMPLE_MESSAGE_CHANNEL from '@salesforce/messageChannel/ExampleMessageChannel__c';
import getObject from '@salesforce/apex/CaseRelatedListApex.getObject';


export default class CaseHistoryLWC extends LightningElement {
        

        @track data = [];
        @track  columns = [
        { label: 'Case Number', fieldName: 'CaseNumber' },
        { label: 'Date', fieldName: 'CreatedDate' },
        { label: 'Plan Id', fieldName: 'PlanID_Text__c' },
        { label: 'Inquiry', fieldName: 'Call_Type__c' },
        { label: 'Transactions', fieldName: 'Call_Type__c' },
        { label: 'Account Maintenance', fieldName: 'Call_Type__c' ,},
        { label: 'Forms', fieldName: 'Call_Type__c'},
        { label: 'Others', fieldName: 'Call_Type__c'},];
        
    arr= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.columns));  
        
        wiredRecords;
        @wire(getObject) wiredCases(value){
                
        
                
                this.wiredRecords=value;
                const {data, error}= value;
                if(data){
                    this.columns=   this.columns.map(col=>{
                            if(col.label === "Inquiry"){
                            this.columns[4]='';
                                this.columns[5]='';
                                this.columns[6]='';
                                this.columns[7]='';
                            //  delete this.arr[4];
                            /// delete this.arr[5];
                            //  delete this.arr[6];
                            //  delete this.arr[7];
                            //  columns=this.arr;
                        }   
                        });
                                console.log(" columns ---", arr);
                    //   this.columns = arr;
                        
                        let tempRecords= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                        let uniqueCaseNumbers = new Set();
                        let uniquePlanIds = new Set();
                        let uniqueCallTypesMap = new Map();
                        //  this.setting();
                        tempRecords = tempRecords.map(row => {
                                if (!uniquePlanIds.has(row.PlanID_Text__c)) {
                                        uniquePlanIds.add(row.PlanID_Text__c);

                                        return {...row,CaseNumber:row.Case__r.CaseNumber , CreatedDate:row.Case__r.CreatedDate};
                                        console.log("temprecords inside -", tempRecords);
                                        
                                }
                                return { ...row,PlanID_Text__c: null};
                                
                    
                        });
                        console.log(" columns ---", this.arr    );
            
                        
                        
                    
                        this.data= tempRecords;
                console.log("temprecords latest -", tempRecords);
                        
                    /*  if( this.columns.columnKey=='accMain')
                        {
                            //  this.columns[5]
                            //  tempRecords = tempRecords.map(row => {
                                //      if (Call_Type__c==='Name Change' ||Call_Type__c==='ACH Add/Change' || Call_Type__c==='Address Change' ||Call_Type__c==='Email Address Update'|| Call_Type__c==='Automatic Bank Draft') {


                                            //  return {...row,CaseNumber:row.Case__r.CaseNumber , CreatedDate:row.Case__r.CreatedDate};
                                            //  console.log("temprecords inside -", tempRecords);
                                    //  }
                                    //  return { ...row,PlanID_Text__c: null};
                            //  });

                        } */
                        
                        
                }

                if(error){
                        console.log("error Occurred!" , error);
                }
        }
            
            setting(){
                    if( this.columns.label=='Transactions'){
                            
                                this.columns[3]='',
                                this.columns[4]='',
                                this.columns[6]='',
                                this.columns[7]='',
                                            
                            console.log("this.columns.label -", this.columns.label);
                    //  return this.columns;
                        console.log("tempRecords!" , tempRecords);
                    }
                    
            }

}
```

HTML:

```html
<template>
        <div style="height: 300px;">
                <h2 slot="title">
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="action:new_note"  title=" Case History"></lightning-icon>
                        <b>Case History</b>
                </h2>

                <lightning-datatable
                        data={data}
                        columns={columns}
                        key-field="Id"
                        show-row-number-column
                        row-number-offset={rowOffset}
                        hide-checkbox-column      
                >
                </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
     
</template>
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to describe the specific problem you're having, what you expect to happen, and the debugging that you have done already.